# Akka Streams inlets and outlets mismatch

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The inlets [] and outlets [BlockOut.out] must correspond to the inlets [] and outlets [BlockOut.out]
```

I have a very simple graph:

```
val g1 = GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val in: Source[ByteString, Any] = Source.single(ByteString(digest))
  val flow: GraphStage[FlowShape[ByteString, ByteString]] = new ReadBlockStage(dataStore, blockingExecutionContext)

  in ~> flow

  SourceShape(flow.shape.out)
}

val sourceGraph: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] = Source.fromGraph(g1)
```

and my flow is defined like this:

```
class ReadBlockStage(dataStore: DataStore, implicit val exceutionContext: ExecutionContext) extends GraphStage[FlowShape[ByteString, ByteString]] with DefaultJsonProtocol {
  val in = Inlet[ByteString]("DigestSpec.in")
  val out = Outlet[ByteString]("BlockOut.out")
  override val shape = FlowShape.of(in, out)
  ...
}
```

Why am I getting this error?  The flow's "out" port is of type `Outlet[ByteString]`, and my `Source` is `Source[ByteString, NotUsed]`.  The error message is very confusing because it looks like the shape and the expected shape are the same.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the issue.  I had forgotten to perform the builder.add() for each of the graph elements.